# Count number of occurrences of a day between two dates SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server, how many 8 day periods do I have between this two dates?

```
@date1 = '2016/11/08'
@date2 = '2017/02/10'
```

Manually I have four 8 day periods between those dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Declare @date1 date = '2016/11/08'
Declare @date2 date = '2017/02/10'

Select count(*)
 From (
        Select Top (DateDiff(DD,@date1,@date2)+1) D=cast(DateAdd(DD,Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select null))-1,@date1) as Date) 
        From master..spt_values n1, master..spt_values n2 
      ) A
 Where DatePart(DAY,D)=8
```

Returns

```
4
```

Comment: NB: This method has a limitation if there are more than 2519 (`select count(1) from master..spt_values `) days between the start and the end date.

Comment: Nice :).  With that sized range you run out of SQL dates before you run out of numbers.  `select dateadd(dd,6345361,'1753-01-01')`

Comment: @JohnLBevan I know the numbers can get ridiculous, but the TOP will maintain the performance

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternate approach using the standard SQL Date functions:

```
 declare @StartDate datetime = '2016-11-08'
, @EndDate datetime = '2023-10-09' --'2017-02-10' 
, @dayOfInterest int = 8 --in case you decided you were interested in a different date

--if you don't care whether or not start date is before or after end date; swap their values...
/*
select @StartDate = min(d)
, @EndDate = max(d)
from (select @StartDate d union select @EndDate) x
*/

select 
case when @StartDate <= @EndDate then
    --if the end date is after or on the start date, we count the number of eighths in between
    datediff(month,@StartDate,@EndDate) --count the number of months between the two dates
    + case when datepart(dd,@StartDate)<=@dayOfInterest then 0 else -1 end --if our range excludes the nth this month, exclude it
    + case when datepart(dd,@EndDate)<@dayOfInterest then 0 else 1 end --if our range includes the nth on the last month, include it
else 
    0 --if the end date is before the start date; we return 0
end
CountTheDays --give the output column a name
```

**Caution**

NB: For the 8th this will work perfectly.
For dates after 28th it isn't reliable (you'd be better off going with [John Cappelletti's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42166058/361842)), as my logic would add 1 day per month, regardless of whether that month contained that day (i.e. if counting the number of 30ths between 1st Jan and 1st March you'd get 2 instead of 1, as my logic assumes Feb 30th to be a valid date.